# How to use text instead of Icon for react-toolbox menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-design, react-toolbox

I am using react-toolbox menu for my website. Based on the example given in the documentation [React-toolbox menu](http://react-toolbox.io/#/components/menu), I can only use icon as my menu. How can I use text for the menu instead?

**Example of what I want to do:**

When I click the blog text which is a menu, the menuItem will be shown.

[image: Example]

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove icon property from MenuItem component

```
 <IconMenu icon={<div>blog</div>} position='topLeft' menuRipple>
  <MenuItem value='download' caption='Download' />
  <MenuItem value='help' caption='Favorite' />
  <MenuItem value='settings' caption='Open in app' />
  <MenuDivider />
  <MenuItem value='signout' icon='delete' caption='Delete' disabled />
 </IconMenu>
```

Comment: This method works,  but then I realized the whole text area is not fully clickable, only by clicking the right position in the text, the MenuItem will show up, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an element to the icon property like that:

`<IconMenu icon={<div>Menu</div>} position='topLeft' menuRipple>`

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has the problem, the solution is to use Menu component instead of IconMenu. Like this :

```
const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = useState(false);
return (
  <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
    <Button label='Actions' onClick={() => setMenuActive(!menuActive)} />
    <Menu position='topRight' active={menuActive} onHide={() => setMenuActive(false)}>
     <MenuItem value='download' caption='Download' />
     <MenuItem value='action' caption='Action' />
    </Menu>
  </div>
);
```